# Bug on socket android reading String

Tags: java, android, c, sockets

I have an App in Android. This App have different Threads. Each thread is a Socket Client TCP. The servers send me ~320 characters per second. Usually the connection is stable and receive the strings correctly, but sometimes one socket or all sockets stop receive data, and seconds after (5 seconds to 50 seconds) socket continue receive data.

I am losing the information of this time. I can't lost this information, is very important. I try doing the server socket in C, C++ and Java, and this occurs always and the bug time is aleatory, for example runs App OK for 2 hours and then the bug appears. Other day I run the App and 4 minutes later The bug appears. I run the App in my Nexus 5, Sony Tablet Z3 Compact and I think is a problem with sockets in SDK because pass on all device.

I post some code to have an idea of my code. I have to say the CPU have a 4% of usage. For last when the socket client is not reading, the server is continuously sending data, but this data lost in Android App. I check Client socket in Linux PC, in Raspberry Pi, C, Java, this issue never happens

I try in Android with Java.Nio sockets, and the last I trying with NDK to see if in low level this issue appears too. Anyone have a similar issue or bug? Can anyone Help me?

```
Date last_data = new Date();
InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(ip);    
Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, port);   
while(socket.isConnected()){
    byte[] data_read = new byte[514];
    //if(socket.getInputStream().available() > 0){
    count = socket.getInputStream().read(data_read);
    String read = new String(data_read).substring(0, count);

    Date now = new Date();
    long time = now.getTime() - last_data.getTime();
    //long diffInSec = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(time);
    if(time > 1200){
         Log.d("LOG", "ERROR SOCKET TCP " + this.ip + ":" + this.port + " - Time: " + String.valueOf(time));
    }
    if (!read.isEmpty()) {
        //Do something

        //Renew Last data receive
        last_data = new Date();
    }else{
        //Never entry
    }
    //}
}
```

Thank you for reading and helping.

Comment: This code isn't C++, but you tagged `C++`.

Answer (score 0):

```
String read = new String(data_read).....
```

That should be

```
String read = new String(data_read, 0, count).....
```

NB testing `isConnected()` is not the correct way to terminate that loop. It won't magically become false when the peer disconnects. You should terminate when `read()` returns -1 or there's an `IOException` other than a read timeout.

Comment: My problem is in socket.getInputStream().read(data_read); He blocked and doesn't read data even the server is sending data. Seconds later continues reading more data, but don't understand why doesn't read some seconds.